# how to unit test spring integration dsl code

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

i was unable to find an simple example to unit test the spring integration dsl, which involves picking up a message from queue and making a rest call.

I looked at the examples https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl but was not clear on qualifiers etc for the below code for which i want to write unit test on.

```
    IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundGateway(connectionFactory)
            .id("inputChannel")
            .destination(sourceQueue)
            .jmsMessageConverter(new MarshallingMessageConverter(jaxbMarshaller())))
            .something to validate and route
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:9999/create)
                            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                            .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Something else is needed in your question to explain more the requirements.

Anyway I'll try to answer in my best feeling on the matter.

Spring Integration Java DSL is nothing more then codding tool to wire beans and build integration components into flows. In the end, at runtime, we just have a set of beans with which we can interact as with any other beans in the application context.

So, if the story is about consuming some destination from JMS and verify what we get from there, there is just enough to run ActiveMQ in the embedded mode - it is as simple as bean for:

```
new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false")
```

Then you use `JmsTemplate` to send some test data to the desired destination (will be created on demand) and consume an Integration message from the channel defined in the mentioned in your question `IntegrationFlow`.

Typically for consuming test data we use a `QueueChannel` and its `receive(long timeout)`. This way we block a unit test until data arrives or timeout is elapsed.

Another way to verify a flow work is with the [Spring Integration Testing Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/testing.html#test-context). From there you can use a `MockIntegration` to replace the real `MessageHandler` in the application context and verify an interaction with the mock afterward.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: I am planning for mock test, thanks for pointing to right documentation. I updated the above example, in the example i am trying to replace jms input for which i wrote the below code         `MessageSource<String> messageSource = () -> new GenericMessage<>("some payload");       mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageSourceFor("inputChannel", messageSource);` I am seeing the following error `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'inputChannel' available` How to i refer to input channel

Comment: That's because `Jms.inboundGateway()` is not a `MessageSource`. It is a `MessagingGatewaySupport`. You can overcome the problem anyway: 1. You need `@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = "inputChannel")`. 2. You really need to add a real channel before the next `.something to validate and route`. 3. Use your mock `messageSource` to call its `receive()` and send the result message to the mentioned channel. I think we might consider to add to the `MockIntegrationContext` something like `substituteMessagingGatewayWithMessagesource()` to let it work automatically without inserting extra channel

Comment: I started writing the integration test using the embedded activemq broker, i am successful in placing the message using jmsTemplate and i can see the message is picked and saved in db. But i am unable to verify the contents of db record as my test are unable to see the record written by integration flow as its in different transaction i believe.

Comment: Well, on this case we can help only if there is a code to play. Although that already doesn’t sound like a unit test and is not related to a general question above...

Comment: My unit & integration tests are https://github.com/NagendraSiram/spring-integration-sample Error description is in the java test code comment

Comment: @ArtemBilan: What if I have a `Jms.inboundAdapter()`? I also get this `No bean named 'xxx' available`.

Comment: Sounds like a separate SO question with more info to understand the context of your issue

Comment: @ArtemBilan I think my problem is more general: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297757/springintegrationtest-annotation-does-not-load-context-as-expected