# @SpringIntegrationTest annotation does not load context as expected

Tags: spring-integration

Normally, when I use `@SpringBootTest` I get the full context of beans. I can the `@Autowire` all kinds of beans that are available after the application has started.
Now, in the scope of `spring-integration-test` libary, the `@SpringIntegrationTest` does not do this.

As the testing module promises, you can use

```
@Autowired
private MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationContext;
```

However, after inspecting the bean map on that instance, I found out there are **no** beans!

Example test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringIntegrationTest
public class AppTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationContext;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        // put breakpoint to inspect field
        System.out.println(mockIntegrationContext);
    }
}
```

When I however run the following code, I get a complete context:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class App2Test {

    @Autowired
    private ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        Assert.isTrue(beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionCount() > 0)
    }
}
```

Why is that? How can I achieve a similar result with `spring-integration-test`?

Reading materials: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html

Answer (score 2):

They are independent annotations; you need both.

**EDIT**

This works fine for me:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@SpringIntegrationTest
public class So52297757ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationContext;

    @Autowired
    private String foo;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println(foo);
        System.out.println(mockIntegrationContext);
    }

}
```

and

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So52297757Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So52297757Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }

}
```

and

```
foo
org.springframework.integration.test.context.MockIntegrationContext@1de5f0ef
```

Comment: thanks, but adding @SpringBootTest to the first class doesn't add beans to the map.

Comment: Works fine for me; see my edit. What "map" are you talking about?

Comment: Wait. Are you confused with the `MockIntegrationContext.beans`? Please, see its purpose in docs: `this.mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageSourceFor()` and similar. That's fully not related to the `applicationContext` per se.

Comment: @GaryRussell When I look at Artem's video from 2017 "Spring Integration 5.0: What's new?", he does not use `@SpringBootTest` in his SpringIntegrationS1p2017MqttToMono example.  He uses `@ContextConfiguration` in combination with `@SpringIntegrationTest`, the MockIntegrationContext is injected and he can access the beans defined outside the test.  Doing that today fails to inject the MockIntegrationContext.  Has it changed to require `@SpringBootTest` for MockIntegrationContext injection to work?